# How to hide or remove the UIwebview when a action is done?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have two `IBActions`. In one action I am loading the `UIWebview` to display a `PDF` File from my bundle. On clicking the other button the whole `UIWebView` should get removed from superview.

I have tried using:

`[webview removeFromSuperview];`

and

`webview.hidden=YES;`

Neither of these are working. They are hiding my `UIWebView` for a second, but then it appears again.

Is is
I have created UIWEBVIEW programatically and added the UIWebvieWDelegate in the interface file. But when initializing the UIWebView I didnt set webview.delegate=self; Is it the problem?

Comment: Have you tried webView = nil;

Comment: Show us some more code. I'm 100% sure you're adding the view whack somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

have you connected `Referencing Outlet` to the class's `@property` in the *Interface Builder*?

If you don't do it, **it would be the a possible reason** why you cannot reach the `UIWebView` in your source code. for your sake, you should check the pointer of `webview`, if it is `nil` chronically, there is 100% you have not connected them each other.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems old question, but also i can see there are almost thousand people have view it, and may have the same problem. so my answer for anyone my have the same issue in the future.
I just been doing something  smiler and want to hide the web view when at a certain action.
I have tried the following

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    process = [ProcessingData new];
    [DetailView setHidden:YES];
    DetailView.hidden = YES;
    [DetailView removeFromSuperview];
    self.DetailView = nil;
}
```

however it is still not working, as i have few labels in the WebView which are don't disappear when the view load, when I looked at the "StoryBoard" i notes that the labels are not subview of the

[image]

can u see the hierarchy of the libels under the WebView, they are subview of the main view, where they suppose to be same as the table view hierarchy

so in may case the WebView is hiding but the labels are not as they are not a part of the Webview.

how to sort this problem, if you really don't need web view use the normal one, otherwise you have to hide all the labels in that view. hope thats helpe

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make a thing like this. The solution that worked for me was to add UIview object as subview to view with the frame of webview and bringing it to top.... When u want to make uiwebview visible, just remove that uiview object from superview.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know obj-c but still posting a solution that worked for me in swift. basically you have to use the main thread to remove the webview.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("\nremoving webview\n")
            self.myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML='';")
            self.myWebView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
```